# Are there any reasonable sources of data on numbers of religious adherents, for different religions, throughout history?

Tags: religion, research, resource

I'm interested in historical trends in religion and wondered if anyone knows of any reasonable sources of data on the number of adherents, for any/all different religions, throughout human history.

Obviously, older numbers would be very approximate estimates - and modern numbers would also likely be rough, given that this is a personal matter and somewhat sensitive in some parts of the world.

Does this information get included in census data - or has it ever been in the past? Do you know of any sources of data on this, even for single periods or religions, that I could use to piece together a fuller picture?

I know about [this](http://www.thearda.com/Archive/), which is great, but fairly recent and major religions only. Anything older, covering more religions?

Comment: No.  There are no reasonable sources of information regarding adherents.  Religiosity and observance are so highly contextual that this is unanswerable.

Comment: Apart from saying 'self-identified' - which would suit my purposes - might there also be a narrower definition of 'adherant' that might make this more tractable?

Comment: No.  Because social and cultural contexts of the past aren't reducible to a modern statistical analysis.  The first part of any census to read, even before collection method, is the assumptions and purposes behind the categories and codings.  Three months ago when I read a review article from 2000 or so (reasonably current in historiography) on religious history, "the prior question" of what religiosity is was still being debated.  The question is unanswerable.

Comment: Are you saying that religion is too subjective to be able to measure *anything* about bulk trends over time? 5000 years ago, zero people would have self-identified as Christians if asked, now millions would - clearly something measurable has changed regarding Christianity over time?

Comment: I'd say it was about [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)% adherents, [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)% non-adherents, and the rest somewhere in between ... (note-to-self: a "42" tag could be useful for questions that insist on a quantitative answer where there is perhaps none ... :)

Comment: Yes, @DuncanLock, that is precisely the point.  See Philip S. Gorski (2000) "Historicizing the Secularization Debate: Church, State, and Society in Late Medieval and Early Modern Europe, ca. 1300 to 1700" American Sociological Review (65:1) Special Issue: "Looking Forward, Looking Back: Continuity and Change at the Turn of the Millenium" pp. 138-167 http://www.jstor.org/stable/2657295

Comment: Thanks, I'll checkout that article and think about it further.

Comment: @DuncanLock Instead of looking for numbers of religious adherents, you might have better luck looking at the numbers of places of worship (churches, mosques, synagogues, etc) over time. Since they would be kept on various tax/ownership records, you might find some interesting data with a little digging.

Comment: Yes, these would also show up in the archaeological record, which would provide additional data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one data point (from [Jakob Burckardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_Burckhardt)'s *The Age of Constantine the Great*) presumably among very many and already self-contradictory (translation courtesy of [Google](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Die%20letzte%20Zeit%20des%20Diocletian%20und%20Maximiam%20ist%20durch%20die%20Martern%20und%20Blutstr%C3%B6me%20der%20grossen%20Christenverfolgung%20in%20einen%20schrecklichen%20Ruf%20gekommen.%20Man%20hat%20sich%20vergebens%20bem%C3%BCht%2C%20den%20Umfang%20derselben%20und%20die%20Zahl%20der%20Opfer%20auch%20nur%20ann%C3%A4hernd%20zu%20ermitteln%2C%20ja%20es%20fehlt%20schon%20die%20Grundlage%20jeder%20Berechnung%2C%20n%C3%A4mlich%20ein%20zuverl%C3%A4ssiges%20Datum%20%C3%BCber%20die%20Zahl%20der%20um%20jene%20Zeit%20%C3%BCberhaupt%20im%20R%C3%B6mischen%20Reich%20vorhandenen%20Christen.%20Nach%20St%C3%A4udlin%20h%C3%A4tten%20sie%20die%20H%C3%A4lfte%20der%20Gesamtbev%C3%B6lkerung%20ausgemacht%2C%20nach%20Matter%20ein%20F%C3%BCnftel%2C%20nach%20Gibbon%20bloss%20ein%20Zwanzigstel%2C%20nach%20La%20Bastie%20ein%20Zw%C3%B6lftel%2C%20welches%20vielleicht%20der%20Wahrheit%20am%20n%C3%A4chsten%20kommt.) :)

> The last time of Diocletian and Maximiam has come through the torture
>   and blood streams of the great persecution of Christians into a
>   horrible reputation. It has tried in vain to determine the amount
>   thereof and the number of victims even close, so it has no basis each
>   calculation, namely a reliable date on the number of existing at all
>   at that time in the Roman Empire Christians. After Staudlin they
>   accounted for half of the total population, according to Matter fifth,
>   according to Gibbon merely one-twentieth, one-twelfth to La Basti,
>   which perhaps comes closest to the truth.

As also indicated in my earlier comment, IMHO you can't hope for any definite answer to a question such as this one, the more so the "older" any conceivable numbers may get.